# Multiple Realms with multiple data models

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is it possible to create two different realms each one using a different data model?

For example: defaultRealm would use the client class as model and myRealm would use products class as model

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't use the same Class in both realms. If you have sensitive data for example, you might want to use a realm, which uses encryption (which slows querying down), while using the default realm for non-sensitive data

Comment: How can you create two Realms on iOS?   I've got it for OS X but not iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a different set of `Object` subclasses in each Realm isn't yet supported, but it will come with https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1584.

Answer (score 26):

As of Realm Swift v0.95.0, the set of classes a given Realm stores can be set via the [`objectTypes` property on `Realm.Configuration`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm/Configuration.html#/s:vVC10RealmSwift5Realm13Configuration11objectTypesGSqGSaMCS_6Object__).

```
let configA = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: realmFileURL,
                                  objectTypes: [Dog.self, Owner.self])
let realmA = Realm(configuration: configA)


let configB = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: otherRealmFileURL,
                                  objectTypes: [Product.self])
let realmB = Realm(configuration: configB)
```

`realmA` can only store instances of `Dog` and `Owner`, while `realmB` can only store instance of `Product`.